# Vista dvd/cd doesn't see disk content and thinks it is a blank cdr/dvdr

Tags: optical-media

CD/DVD oddness...
I put in a dvd or cd and vista thinks it is a blank dvd/cd and asks me to label it.  Oddly enough if I right click on the drive and select eject then reinsert the disk vista recognizes the content.  This happens to me on 3 different vista machines (all dells).

Comment: At risk of pointing out the obvious, do you have the latest SP / hotfixes?

Comment: These are all fully patched machines

Answer (score 2):

I have seen similar issues and it can be sometimes attributed to corrupt or missing upper and lower filters (installed by Burning Software, etc).

(Please note the below is very similar to Mark Allens link...unfortunately NoScript was causing me not to see his link...while it is a different KB I linked, it is for the same issue (which can effect even non-upgraded PC's)

A quick warning, modifying your registry can cause undesired results...so take what I put below with caution.

1. Click Start
     Collapse this imageExpand this image
     Start button
     , and then click All Programs.
2. Click Accessories, and then click Run.
3. Type regedit, and then click OK.
     Collapse this imageExpand this image
     User Access Control permission
     If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.
4. In the navigation pane, locate and then click the following registry subkey:
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
5. In the right pane, click UpperFilters.

   Note You may also see an UpperFilters.bak registry entry. You do not have to remove that entry. Click UpperFilters only. If you do not see the UpperFilters registry entry, you still might have to remove the LowerFilters registry entry. To do this, go to step 8.
6. On the Edit menu, click Delete.
7. When you are prompted to confirm the deletion, click Yes.
8. In the right pane, click LowerFilters.

   Note If you do not see the LowerFilters registry entry, unfortunately this content cannot help you any further. Go to the "Next Steps" section for information about how you can find more solutions or more help on the Microsoft Web site.
9. On the Edit menu, click Delete.

   10. When you are prompted to confirm the deletion, click Yes.
   11. Exit Registry Editor.
   12. Restart the computer.

Additionally, you can take a look at the MS KB. Q314060.

Comment: Just a note, most Dells come with Roxio software, which can get finicky.  Make sure you checked for any updates to your burning software (Roxio Drag-to-Disc/DirectCD especially)

Comment: I have done similar to make my DVD burner work...Vista just never has handled media very well.  (not hating..just my mileage)

Answer (score 1):

My bet is on CD burning Software.
[this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929461) link can help you to digg in, as Mark Allen pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow there are so many things to check.

1) Same model of Dell? (Could be the specific model of reader/burner.)

2) Are the three machines in close proximity? (I've had an entire row of machines lose their DVD readers... the top row... because of the heat, over time.

3) What does it say in the event log on those machines? Anything regarding the CD?

4) Does it do it to Audio CDs too?

5) If you upgraded to Vista, it could be [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929461).

Comment: All different models 1 precision laptop, 1 dell precision workstation and 1 dell optiplex.  They do all use the same cd burning software...  All 3 are in different locations, nothing in event log, haven't tried audio... will try, none are upgrades